# Update Lookup(Campaign) Lead value via trigger

Tags: trigger, lookup, leads, field-update, campaign

I have a Lookup(Campaign) field Consumer_Newsletter__c set up on the Lead object.  The Lookup(Campaign) field populates the Campaign Name on the Lead record.

I'm trying to put together Apex code that (1) updates the Consumer_Newsletter__c value; then (2) fires a managed package class et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate() on the Lead.  The one consideration is I have Workflows running which update the Lead values when inserted/updated.

Can someone help me troubleshoot what I have so far?

```
trigger Trig_Lead on Lead (after insert, after update) {   
    static boolean hasCampaign = false;
    if(trigger.isUpdate&&trigger.isAfter){
      for(lead l : trigger.new){
        if(l.consumer_newsletter__c != null){
          hasCampaign = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if(hasCampaign==true){
      et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Lead');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Omar, welcome to the community. What exactly is the issue you're facing - you say "troubleshoot," so is there a compilation or runtime error you currently are trying to debug? I see right away that you're not actually performing any DML operations in your after trigger

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted appears to not meet either requirement you listed:

- the Consumer_Newsletter__c value on Lead is never set
- et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate() is never called on a Lead - you are passing the literal String 'Lead' to this method, and no actual reference.

Additionally, any changes this trigger made would not be "saved," as you never `update` the records - this is necessary in an after trigger.

I've updated your code to pass the correct Lead records to the package method (and removed an unnecessary variable, hasCampaign); I also added a DML statement so that the changes are pushed to the database. If you provide how the value of Consumer_Newsletter__c should be determined, I can help you add that logic in as well.

```
trigger Trig_Lead on Lead (after insert, after update) {   
    if (trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter) {
      for (Lead l : trigger.new) {
        // we will set l.Consumer_Newsletter__c here
        if (l.Consumer_Newsletter__c != null) {
          et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate(l);
        }
      }
      update trigger.new;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian.  To explain,  I have a FormAssembly web form writing signups to a custom object, then some workflow business rules writing them to the Lead/Campaign objs (ie Lead insert + add to Campaign).   I was getting false positives when testing the Apex and running SOQL debugging (the consumer_newsletter__c value updates asynchronously, and not when the triggerUtility method was fired).  I'm a newbie to Apex, so thanks for pointing out my errors ie String 'Lead'.   One question - should the trigger be defined for a List or a Set of ids?  As-is, the code would call for every Lead.  Thanks!

Comment: @Omarr - Brian's trigger is properly bulkified; `Trigger.new` is a list and will execute on all Leads in the batch. A more interesting question is whether managedPackage `et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate()` can handle a bulk update request with a list of leads-- because if it does SOQL/DML, then it will be doing SOQL/DML inside of a for loop which is bad